# Xml Document Creation

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I want to create a xml file with the following format,

```
<myFiles>
  <name>myname</name>
  <place>myplace</place>
  <mydata>
     <today>1-1-2011</today>
     <time>1 PM</time>
     <driving>
       <car>audi</car>
       <bus>volvo</bus>
     </driving>
  </mydata>
</myFiles>
```

I have 2 options

1. Using a model class to build the xml
2. Using a dictionary to store details, then build json from that dictionary

Which is the best option, or any other method available? It is a big document and may have data of more than 100 users.

Thanks in advance

Comment: <myFiles><name>myname</name><place>myplace</place><mydata><today>1-1-2011</today><time>1 PM</time><driving><car>audi</car><bus></bus></driving></mydata></myFiles> This is my sample xml file.stackoverflow doesnot allow me to add this code with original data

Comment: Does it have to be in that exact format? If not, you could just represent all of your data as classes and use .Net's inbuilt XmlSerialization. Even if it does need to be in the above format, using distinct classes and implementing a an XmlSerializer for your classes means you can simplify a lot of your To and From xml methods.

Comment: Thanks dash. this is actually the format. So any sample code available

Comment: @dash agreed with you, Prasobth check this link http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization

Comment: Thanks Damith. This is good method and also this is what i am looking for

Comment: Damit still i have some another problem that is when i create a lus 
<myFiles>
  <name>myname</name>
  <place>myplace</place>
  <mydata>
  <today>1-1-2011</today>
   <time>1 PM</time>
   <driving>
   <car>audi</car>
   <bus>volvo</bus>
   </driving>
  </mydata>
<mydata>
  <today>1-1-2011</today>
  <time>1 PM</time>
  <driving>
  <car>audi</car>
  <bus>volvo</bus>             
  </driving>
</mydata>
</myFiles> list will appear in another list is it possible to avoid

Answer (score 2):

Option one of using model class seems to be the better one from code maintainability point of view.

Comment: Its ok but again i have a doubt that is, when i use model class i have 3 xml array in that document so there i want to use 4 class know.

Answer (score 1):

The most flexible and performance optimized way is using [`XmlWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx).